# Python literally ghosts a line and skips calling a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I know this might not make much sense. There is a function that is calling another function which should call `selenium.webdriver.Chrome().get('some_website')`, here's a simplified version of the code(which works perfectly fine):

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


def func1(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)


def func2():
    driver = Chrome()
    func1(driver, 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    func2()
```

Because most probably this going to be met with skepticism, I made a gif showing this weird phenomenon:

[image: wtf]

and here's the problematic code which shouldn't be, it's crystal clear there is something odd here, and i tried the following btw:

- tried switching the interpreter to python3.7
- reinstalled selenium
- ran the code from the terminal
- created a virtual environment and ran the code

And all of the above led to the same outcome

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from lxml import html
import time


def get_table_id(website):
    """
    Get table html id value.
    Args:
        website: url containing supported domains.

    Returns:
        website respective table id.
    """
    if 'free-proxy.cz' in website:
        return 'proxy_list'
    if 'proxyrack' in website:
        return 'proxy_table'
    raise ValueError(f'Unsupported website {website}')


def scrape_page(driver, page, wait_time=0):
    """
    Scrape a page from the following websites:
    - http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/main/
    - https://www.proxyrack.com/free-proxy-list/
    Args:
        driver: selenium.webdriver class
        page: url.
        wait_time: seconds to wait for page load.

    Yields:
        dictionary per scraped ip address.
    """
    driver.get(page)
    content = driver.page_source
    if wait_time:
        time.sleep(wait_time)
    tree = html.fromstring(content)
    columns = [
        tree.xpath(f'//*[@id="proxy_list"]/tbody//tr//td[{i}]//text()')
        for i in range(1, 12)
    ]
    columns = [
        [item for item in row if 'adsbygoogle' not in item] for row in columns[:3]
    ]
    if 'proxyrack' not in page:
        columns[0] = [columns[0][i] for i in range(1, len(columns[0]), 2)]
    assert (
        len(set(len(item) for item in columns)) == 1
    ), f'row length mismatch \n{columns}'
    for row in zip(*columns):
        yield dict(zip(('ip_address', 'port', 'protocol'), row))


def scrape_pr_pages(total_pages=765):
    driver = Chrome()
    scrape_page(driver, 'http://free-proxy.cz/en/', 15)  # ?????
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="dynatable-pagination-links-proxy_table"]/li[8]/a'
    ).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    print(driver.page_source)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape_pr_pages()
```

Comment: The shorter code that you have provided runs just fine. I am getting the stackoverflow login page as expected.

Comment: `scrape_page` is an iterator (`yield` call at end). You don't seem to be iterating the result.

Comment: @Yatin yes, I know and i've indicated that it works

Comment: @sK500 I could reproduce your issue in both chrome and firefox... I am not entirely sure why the code isn't even entering the `scrape_page` function... I am looking into it

Comment: @Mike67 thanks, I should `yield from scrape_page()` my fault but it's funny

Comment: @Mike67 is right! I commented out the last 2 lines in `scrape_page` function and the code runs fine!

Comment: @Yatin I think Mike67's comment is correct, this most probably happened because I merged 2 functions and while copying certain parts, I overlooked that i should yield from the function instead of calling it, anyway I haven't tested this yet but most probably it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copying my comment to answer)

In the `scrape_page`, the results are send back using `yield`. This converts the function to an iterator. To process the results, you need to iterate them.

```
for row in scrape_page(driver, 'http://free-proxy.cz/en/', 15):
   print(row)
```

As the OP mentioned, removing the `yield` call and returning the full dictionary also solved the issue.